# Cassandra Prepared Statement in CQL3 using thrift

Tags: java, database, cassandra, thrift, cql3

I'm looking for information about prepared statements(ps) livecycle.

I'm using BasePoolableObjectFactory provided by apache to make connection pool. Then, using TSocket and TTransport, I'm making an object from Cassadra.Client class. This object has methods to execute cql3 queries. Also the object has method to prepare and execute cql3 query, i.e. we can make prepared statements using thrift.

Where are prepared statements stored? In database server or they exist as long as the object exist?

If they are stored in database server, how can I get then, without creating them again?
If they are stored in object, what is prepared then, when each time query is submitted to the server?

I'm asking, cos I want to know when it is worth making prepared statements. Because if I make a prepared statement, execute it once and close the connection, then there is no need to make prepared statements at all.

Comment: Actually I found some answers.
Prepared statements are stored in server. When we make PS, cassandra returns an id. Using this id we can access it later on. IMO we will be able to access the PS via this id from anywhere else. But how we can delete this statement from Cassdra? Is restarting Cassandra server the only way ?

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements are cached per-connection.  (You access them with the id that the server gives you back as the result of the prepare call.)

So no, there is no point in using them for one-shot queries.  This is common across any prepared statement design.

Comment: I have checked execution speed and...prepared statements are faster when queries exceed 100 per connection. So in normal case they are just slower.